# What are the QGIS words for my 4 types of data?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, vector-layer, gis-principle

My project has 4 types of data:

1. a raster satellite view (Google Maps), to be the base layer and geolocated by three points (CSV) that apply to visible points on the raster map;
2. **individual points**: different types of trees, each type with a slightly different symbol;
3. lines (paths) each marked by a series of points (CSV);
4. areas (e.g.gardens) which need to be filled with a colour.

I understand a raster layer, my image is already installed in one, but not yet geolocated.
I assume lines and areas are both vector layers.
But what is a layer with individual points called??

(All my data is UTM 18N CSV from a Garmin 65.)

Comment: Your question is unclear, I suggest to read this : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#exploring-data-formats-and-fields and to edit your question...

Comment: J.R., with apologies, to me it's the documentation that's unclear, beginning with a flood of acronyms I've never hear of. I'm just getting started, and want to add simple data to layers in QGIS of a city park...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every layer that is not bitmap-like is called a vector layer.

So however counter-intuitive it may seem, a point layer is also a vector layer. After all: every point in such a layer is still pointed out by a vector from the origin.

Comment: "Every layer that is not bitmap-like is called a vector layer." That is not true, see the answer by @J.R and my comment there: there are also alphanumeric (non geometric) layers as well as mesh data and pointcloud layers.

Comment: @Babel: True. +1

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to add data to QGIS there are 3 main type :

- Raster data : data stored in "picture" format (png, jpeg, tiff, ...)
  this is for image/picture (like satellite/aerial view) or matrices of
  discrete cells that represent features / phenomena (like elevation or
  temperature)
- Vector data : this is data in gis specific format (there are many
  format either as file or in a database) that hold geometry of object
  (point, line or surface) and information relative to these object
  (attribute)
- Alphanumeric data : this is data in formatted as a table (csv,
  xls,...) that don't have geometry but only attribute (some of these
  attribute may describe the geometry so it's possible to display it as
  a vector geographic layer)

Comment: And, just for completeness, apart from these main types other more special types: mesh data and pointclouds.